# Selecting tables from a non dbo query schema results in error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some tables in a car schema.

I changed my user's default schema to `car` but when I try to do the following:

```
select * from toyota
```

I still get the following:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Invalid object name 'toyota'.

I have to specify `car` before it works like so:

```
select * from car.toyota
```

I already did this:

```
ALTER USER mex WITH NAME = mex;

ALTER USER mex WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = car;
```

Is there something else I'm missing? How can I keep the `car` schema but still be able to query it with just the table name?

Answer (score 1):

usually you gotta do this before you use select statements:

```
USE [Car]
GO
SELECT * FROM TOYOTA
```

This is ofcourse, if you're using Latin1_General_CI_AI collation. Otherwise, you'll have to be really careful with the case-sensitive database.

Comment: i'm getting the same results then :(

Comment: @TanyaXrum does `toyota` exist in `car`? Can I see your Schema - a screenshot showing the necessary details maybe?

Comment: yup, everything is there. when i say select * from car.toyota it works. both the schema and the db names are car

Comment: The question is about schemas. `USE` has nothing to do with schemas.

Answer (score 0):

The changing of the user's default schema should do the trick. So, I have to ask the dumb question: are you running this query as the user whose default schema you changed?